# global type imports stripped from generated type declarations

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am generating declarations for a library I am working on, and one file, I import a type from a third party library that is declared in node modules like this

```
//node_modules
declare module 'thirdpartylib' {
    global {
      interface MyInterface {
         ....

//my code
import { MyInterface } from 'thirdpartylib'
....
```

the import from thirdpartylib ends up being stripped out of my generated declaration files because it's global, so in the file it is just being referenced without an import.

Is there a way to keep these global types from being stripped from the generated declaration files?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this with imports is still an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36812), but you can use the [reference directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-types-) to achieve the similar of a side-effect type import:

```
/// <reference types="thirdpartylib"/>

// Use the interface from the global namespace
function foo(bar: MyInterface) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe reference directives will help, though the linked issue is something different. I have a specific type I want to import from the library, but it's also declared globally, in addition to being imported, and that is causing the imports to be stripped from my generated d.ts files, even though I don't want that.

Comment: I guess I see how being able to import the module without specifying a type will prevent it from being stripped out. though I'd rather just be able to keep my imports there regardless